# What does the white screen of death say?

Tags: pt

PT is a free downloadable game for the PlayStation 4.  It's a psychological horror game.

At some point during the game, an intentional white screen of death is displayed.  The text on it is small and the screen passes in just a couple of seconds, so I couldn't catch exactly what it said.

I've searched for a bit online, but I couldn't find the full text.  And quite frankly, it scared me so much that I'm not willing to play through it again to get to that point, haha.  And I'd have only the same few seconds, regardless.

So what was that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, at 1:30 you can read the text in this video:

The English part reads:

> Knowing you, I was sure you'd notice this game and play it. I will never - can never -forget that day 20 years ago. I have something to tell you. Contact me -J.

I translated the different languages, and they're practically the same thing.

Comment: Oh, wow, I never thought to look for a YouTube playthrough.  Nice find!

Comment: @asteri. Alternatively, you could've pressed the `Share` button to keep a copy of the last 15 minutes your PS4 recorded, then view the recording on your PS4. At least I think you could do that, P.T. isn't out yet in my region so I can't check if it'd work; some games can restrict recording after all.